# How to plot multiple destination and provide Route for the user in Google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, path-finding

I've been researching for a long time in finding tutorials.

[This is what i want to attain/make, Credit to Voyage: Route Planner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk2Zl.png)

That application itself is similar for what i want to make.

Questions are:

1. -How to plot multiple destination and provide Route for the user in Google map?
2. -Is there any books/tutorials/website that i can read/use/watch to learn more about google map?
3. [How can i give the directions to the user after i provide the route? or how can i do this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rMcX.png)

-I've already saw similar question like this but then it is written in Javascript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. **How to plot multiple destination and provide Route for the user in Google map?**

   - As far as I know, multiple destinations support hasn't been an added feature yet for Android as also discussed in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/DZ1i3phNNxc).
   - However, you can get some ideas about getting directions for multiple destinations from the given [suggestion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/DZ1i3phNNxc/WvEujD_rVVYJ) in Google Maps Help Forum and routing from this YouTube video - [Google Maps Routing Multiple Destinations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL97d9WCPzM)
2. **Is there any books/tutorials/website that i can read/use/watch to learn more about google map?**

   You may use these helpful references, video and others

   - To plan a route through a series of up to 23 locations using the Google Maps Directions API, you can use [Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints).
   - [Android Location API - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)
3. **How can i give the directions to the user after i provide the route?**

   - As discussed in [Directions Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests), this can be done by sending HTTPS or HTTP requests and adding certain parameters with the following format:

     > `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/outputFormat?parameters`

I hope that helps.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, Thank you! but then i'm looking for more better answer with example code that i can deal with. I bookmarked every link that you give! It really does help.
I'm still waiting for someone who can give better answers! Thanks again :)